# Disable pull-up resistor on pps-gpio pin

Tags: gpio, device-tree

I am using the `pps-gpio` dtoverlay. My `/boot/config.txt` has these lines:

```
# Expect the GPS 1PPS pin to be connected to GPIO3
dtoverlay=pps-gpio,gpiopin=3
```

Problem is, that the GPS Module (SkyTraq Venus) goes into a debug mode if the PPS pin is pulled high while power is applied. According to [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=24491), GPIO3 is pulled high by default during boot. I confirmed this on my RPI3.

When I connect PPS to GPIO18, which is pulled low during boot, it works just fine. However, I'm stuck with GPIO3, since my circuit boards are already manufactured.

`sudo gpio -g mode 3 down` has no effect. Is there another way to disable the internal pull-up, or even enable a pull-down, while keeping the `pps-gpio` dtoverlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pins 3/5 (GPIO 2/3) have hard-wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3 fitted (so they can function as the I2C bus).

You can not disable these pull-ups in software.

You will have to physically unsolder the resistor.

See [Raspberry Pi schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md).

Comment: Thanks! Would you add a link to documentation or schematic that shows the resistor, please?